# Zoom and Pan in Enhanced Scatter Power BI

Tags: typescript, powerbi

I was just enhancing more the enhanced scatter in order to add a zoom and pan in it. I added the code for it. but the problem is my visual in the Power BI web has gone invisible. I've added the screen shot for the visual.

[image]

following code is of the constructor

```
this.axisGraphicsContext = this.svg
.append("g")
.classed(EnhancedScatterChart.AxisGraphicsContextClassName, true);
this.svg.call(this.zoom);
```

following is the code in the update function

```
this.zoom= d3.behavior.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 10])
.on("zoom", this.zoomed.bind(this));
```

And following is the Zoomed function.

```
private zoomed() {
this.axisGraphicsContext.attr("transform", "translate(" + 
((<any>d3.event).translate) + ")scale(" + ((<any>d3.event).scale) + ")");}
```